# Limiting node access to certain users based on an entity reference field. Which hook to use for when node is viewed?

Tags: nodes, hooks, users

Scenario:

"Teams" content type has user [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field.

"Manager" role can add teams to nodes they have created and the teams will change often.

Members of the team can only view the nodes (and nodes that reference that node through another entity reference field) whenever their team is assigned to them.

For these content types, performance isn't an issue. What I want to do is use a series of `views_get_view_result` when the node is viewed and redirect away from the node if necessary. That part is easy.

What is the best hook to use for when the node is viewed and I can run my views to find out if the user should view it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In similar situation I used [hook_entity_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_access/8.2.x). Also there is [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.2.x) so you can use the `hook_node_access`.